# My code prevents user from exiting field, but it still isn't working

Tags: vb.net, validation, datagridview

I'm trying to find a way to prevent a user from exiting a datagridviewcell if they provide the wrong input. For the datagridview column in question, I want to prevent the user from entering in negative numbers including zero and blank fields. Right now I'm able to prevent this input, and display an appropriate message, but I don't know how to prevent the user form exiting the cell after the message is displayed. My code is shown below. If anyone has any suggestions or answers for this problem I would greatly appreciate any help you may give.

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
    If (e.ColumnIndex = 2) Then
        Dim cellData = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
        If cellData Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(cellData) OrElse cellData.ToString = String.Empty Then
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Be Empty")
            e.Cancel = True
        ElseIf cellData <= 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Negative Numbers and Zero Not Allowed")
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Sub



        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: your code now will prevent user from leaving the cell, isn't it ? .. so what do you want now ?

Comment: Yes, it now prevents the user from exiting the datagridivewcell, but after changing to the correct response the messagebox keeps telling the user the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way ..

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating    

    If (e.ColumnIndex = 2) Then
        Dim cellData = e.FormattedValue 

        If cellData Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(cellData) OrElse cellData.ToString = String.Empty Then
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Be Empty")
            e.Cancel = True
        Else
            If val(cellData) <= 0 Then
               MessageBox.Show("Negative Numbers and Zero Not Allowed")
               e.Cancel = True
               Exit Sub
            Endif    

        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

it's you again ;-) Try using `SendKeys` and use `CellEndEdit` event. This is not perfect solution but at least it will give the job done (hopefully). See code below:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit

    If (e.ColumnIndex = 0) Then 'checking value for column 1 only
        Dim cellValue As Integer
        If (Int32.TryParse(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value, cellValue)) Then
            If cellValue < 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Negative Numbers Not Allowed") 'This prevents negative numbers
                SendKeys.Send("+{Tab}")
            End If
        Else
            Dim testValue As String = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
            If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(testValue)) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Name Cannot Be Empty")
                SendKeys.Send("+{Tab}")
            End If
        End If

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Hello again! Thanks again for your answer. When I tried this I'm getting an error about a conversion from null to db is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DataGridView.CellValidating` Event, and set `e.Cancel = true`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx

Comment: yes :): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit.aspx (edit: sorry, i realise that's not quite what you want - but what's the problem with changing event?)

Comment: When I put my code within the cellvalidating event it only shows the "negative numbers not allowed" messagebox, no matter what I put into the cell